# For which $a \in \mathbb{R}$ $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^a}$ converges and for which $a$ it converges absolutely

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

as mentioned in the title I want to find the values of $a$ for which series $\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^a}$ is convergent and for which values of $a$ it is absolutely convergent. Is my solution alright?

(1) absolute convergence:
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \left|\dfrac{(-1)^n}{n^a}\right| = \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \dfrac{1}{n^a}$$
Series of this form is convergent for $a > 1$.

(2) convergence:
My idea is to show that by the Leibniz's alternating series test. I have to show that

- $\left|u_{n+1}\right| \leq \left|u_{n}\right|$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty} u_n = 0$

1. Clearly for $a > 0, n \geq 1\;$ $$(n+1)^a > n^a \Rightarrow \dfrac{1}{(n+1)^a} < \dfrac{1}{n^a} \Rightarrow\left|u_{n+1}\right| \leq \left|u_{n}\right|$$
2. $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^a} = 0$

The above reasoning does not work for $a < 0$ since if $a$ is negative then $\lim_{n\to\infty} \dfrac{1}{n^a} \neq 0$
$$$$

Comment: Yea I think it is correct.

Comment: It is well known that $\sum_nn^{-p}$ converges iff $p>1$.